# Android Sync data from Web server to SQLite Local DB

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to syncing the data from SQL web server into Android SQLite database, using Android [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) I can find and get the data from web server successfully but the application is crashed when I try to insert the result (data) into SQLite DB.

This is the source code of inserting data into local SQLitedatabase

```
    public long syncDB(String id, String kr_wd, String my_wd) {

    String KEY_ID = "_id";
    String KEY_KR = "kr_word";
    String KEY_MYN = "myn_word";
    String KEY_SYNC = "sync_db";

SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_ID, id);
values.put(KEY_KR, kr_wd);
values.put(KEY_MYN, my_wd);
values.put(KEY_SYNC, 1);


return db.insert("words",null, values);
//db.close();

}
```

And here's the process which attempt to insert results into SQLite DB.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 

                        String word_id =json_data.getString("id");
                        String k_words = json_data.getString("kr_word");
                        String m_words =json_data.getString("myn_word");

                        al.add(word_id);  //id
                        al1.add(k_words); //korea
                        al2.add(m_words);  //myanmar

                        db.syncDB(word_id, k_words, m_words);

                    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the error presented in the Logcat?

Comment: If there is some output from logcat when it crashes it would help!